# ModelForm's metaclass prevents adding of extra fields

Tags: python, django, django-forms, metaclass

I'm writing a mixin class to dynamically add extra fields to a ModelForm which sublasses it.

The new fields are generated in the mixin's `__init__` method. See bellow:

mixin class code (strongly shortened & simplified):

```
class ForeignFieldsMixin(object):
    # …
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        # …
        instance = kwargs.get('instance')
        self.fields[extra_field_name] = fields_for_model(fmodel, (fldname,))
        # ^^^^^^ here a new field instance is added
        self.fields[extra_field_name].initial = 'some value'
        # ^^^^^^ here is set an inital value for the new field 
        # …
```

However form's class still refuses to list the new field name in its `Meta.fields`:

```
class ContactAdminForm(ForeignFieldsMixin, forms.ModelForm):
    # …
    class Meta:
        model   = Contact
        fields  = ('title', 'extra_field_name',)
```

and fails with the following exception

```
File "../lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/forms/models.py", line 215, in __new__
    raise FieldError(message)
FieldError: Unknown field(s) (extra_field_name) specified for Contact
```

I do suspect `ModelForm's` metaclass (or of some of its ancestors) at the time of class *definition* ie. before classes are instantiated raises this exception as it not yet knows about new field names added.

I do not know if I'm taking this from the wrong side as the documentation is rather sparse in this area. I would really like avoid monkey-patching of `ModelForm's` metaclass.

Is there some other way how to simulate the basic in-code fields definition to satisfy Django's class model with its metaclasses protectors but do it dynamically with a generally applicable class/function ?

Comment: I don't see where you define 'extra_field_name' var in your __init__ method.
Also, you should probably call super on the init method of the form class that's derived from it - super(ForeignFieldsMixin, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)

Comment: I do call `super`, don't worry. `extra_field_name` is generated on the fly but it does not matter. This example how the new fields are generally created.

Answer (score 0):

You don't want or need to specify your extra fields in the `fields` tuple. You're adding them manually in the `__init__`, so putting them in `fields` is irrelevant.

Comment: So how can a set the extra fields to be used in a form ? In addition I'd like to be placed at specified place, like between original fields. Now the form is rendered but added extra fields are missing.

Comment: You do it by adding Field instances to `self.fields`. Although I don't understand what you're trying to do with `fields_for_model`: each entry in self.fields is supposed to be an actual Field, not a dict of fields which is what's returned by that function. And ordering is irrelevant: it sounds like you're outputting your form with `form.as_p`, which is really just a quick prototyping tool and shouldn't really be used in proper code. Specify your fields individually in the template.

Comment: Thanks for the anwser. I can check form's `self.fields` does contain the new field and is set to intial value however still missing in a form. Form *does not have a template* as it gets generated when assigned to a `django.contrib.admin.options.ModelAdmin` and registered with `admin.site.register`. Loosing ideas here. Thanks for your time.

Comment: I'm trying to use `django.forms.models.fields_for_model` function to get `Field` instance as a generic way to retrieve selected existing fields of related foreign model.